# How to do `pod trunk push` to replace an existing version of podspec

Tags: cocoapods

I already did a `pod trunk push` for a podspec version. Can I push it again and overwrite the existing one?
I tried it but it gives me this error.

```
$ pod trunk push Parse-iOS-SDK.podspec
Validating podspec
 -> Parse-iOS-SDK (1.2.21)

[!] Unable to accept duplicate entry for: Parse-iOS-SDK (1.2.21)
```

Is there a similar command like `git push -f` force push it?

Ref:
http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2017 Edit: You can now delete pods on trunk, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317506/902968)

Previous answer:

You cannot overwrite a spec using trunk. You should just push a new version with your changes. You can also submit a pull request to the specs repo but we recommend just pushing a new version.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is here I like to have the pod version to be the same as the SDK version. So it would be nice to be able to update the existing version. I guess I'll have to do it via a pull request, which takes some time.

Comment: Yep you'll have to. It probably won't take that long.

Comment: This is no longer true (please see my answer below)

Answer (score 41):

It is now possible to do this by first deleting the pod, and then re-pushing it:

```
pod trunk delete NAME VERSION
```

Then

```
pod trunk push PODSPEC
```

There should be a really good reason to do so, however, and the best practice is to never delete versions but instead push new ones (what Keith said).

Comment: If I delete and then re-push can I re-push the same version? I.e. If I delete v1.2.0 can I push v1.2.0 again. I have to fix something in documentation only but I cannot change the version.

Comment: Correct, you can do exactly that.

I think that in general, any time the change affects only the contents of the podspec but not the underlying library, it is legitimate to be able to republish the podspec at the same version (especially if the podspec version is tied to the library version).

Comment: The documentation and the commands clearly said I would not be able to push the the same version if I deleted it. However, I went ahead anyway and it worked perfectly!

Comment: In my case, pod trunk delete returned me with an error but deleted specified version and I was able to push same version again.

Comment: I got an error as well, but in the end it seemed to work ok.